# Move files in php with move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have a question, now all my video files are in `/videos` now I want to move all my files in `/videos/2014/05` or /`videos/2014/06`...in my database I have a field call date(when the video 
was uploaded) now how to create this script to make folders `/2014/05` and moved all videos there?

I tried an example but not received.

```
    public function move()
    {
        $today_folders = date('Y') .'/'. date('m'). '/' ;

        if ( !file_exists(  $this->config->item("multimedia_path") . 'images/'. $today_folders) ){
        $old_umask = umask(0);
        mkdir( $this->config->item("multimedia_path") . 'videos/'. $today_folders, 0777, true );
        umask($old_umask);
        $this->load->database();
        $articles=$this->db->query("SELECT *FROM videos  ORDER BY date DESC");
        $source = "videos/";
        $destination = "videos/".$today_folders;

        foreach ($articles as $file) {
        if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;
        if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
             $delete[] = $source.$file;
         }
        }

        foreach ($delete as $file) {
        unlink($file);
}

    }
```

Comment: stackoverflow isn't your personal codemonkey squad, paste your code and maybe the community can help you

Comment: You're not accessing your array of results correctly, what columns are in your videos table?

Comment: id   title    mp4_video   date

Comment: @user3744761 And which of those columns is your file name? I'm going to guess mp4_video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function move()
{
    if ( !file_exists(  $this->config->item("multimedia_path") . 'images/'. $today_folders) ){
    $old_umask = umask(0);

    $this->load->database();
    // Assuming mp4_video is your file name
    $videos=$this->db->query("SELECT mp4_video, date FROM videos  ORDER BY date DESC");

    $source = "videos/";

    foreach ($videos as $video) {
        // Load the destination for the video based on the date it was uploaded, assuming your DB wrapper converts date into a DateTime object, if not let me know it's type(eg int because it's a timestamp, or string because it's a mysql datetime, or whatever)
        $destination = $this->config->item("multimedia_path") . 'videos' . $video['date']->format('/Y/m/d/');
        // Again, assuming mp4_video is your filename
        $file = $video['mp4_video'];

        mkdir( $destination, 0777, true);

        if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
           $delete[] = $source.$file;
        }
    }

    umask($old_umask);
    foreach ($delete as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error of this line:  $destination = $this->config->item("multimedia_path") . 'videos' . $video['date']->format('/Y/m/d/');

Comment: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Comment: That's because your database wrapper doesn't convert to a datetime object, what is the type of it, like I asked in the comment above the line?

Comment: But there is mote videos an I got 504 Gateway Time-out

Comment: If you're running this in the browser and getting a timeout try making the timeout infinite: `set_timeout(0);` or if you don't have the ability to do that because your host is restricted I'll see what I can do about making it load across multiple pages(IE handles 100 per page, and reloads the page continuously until they're all done).